# Is it possible to scrape all viewable images + the tagged location of one of your friends on facebook?

Tags: facebook, image-processing, web-scraping, data-mining

I want to select a user (whose images are public and viewable to me, aka a current friend on facebook) and download all viewable pictures of that person, along with the location of the tag of them in that picture.  This is all publicly available to me anyway, so it shouldn't be an issue, I'm just not sure how to extract the tagged location on the image.

Is this something oyu can do through the Facebook API or through some other means?  How would you do it?

Comment: "publicly available" does not imply that the "terms of service" allow you to scrape the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information won't be available via their Graph API because getting user info requires the user to authorize your app, or the person must be friends with the user that approved your app.  You could scrape Facebook's site but this is against their terms of service, and is tricky because they have a lot of measures put in place to prevent scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ask your users for the `friends_photos` permission in order to gain access to that information.
  **Downloading a users photos with out his/her explicit authorization is a very nasty and intrusive thing to do (in addition to violating facebooks platform policies).**  If I were to see this behavior the application would defiantly be reported and the changes are that your personal account would also be deactivated or prevented from opening new applications until the violating application issue is dealt with accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use a script like the AppleScript below, even though it only makes a list of the URLs of thumbnails and not full-size images, and it does not get tagged locations.

```
paragraphs of (do shell script "cat /tmp/ids_of_users")
repeat with user in result
    set s to "open -gagoogle\\ chrome https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=" & user & "\\&sk=photos_albums"
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        close windows
        repeat until exists window 1 -- the open command sometimes results in an `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed` error
            do shell script s
            delay 5
        end repeat
        repeat while loading of tabs of window 1 contains true
            delay 1
        end repeat
      tell active tab of window 1
          set albums to execute javascript "o='';a=document.querySelectorAll('.albumThumbLink');for(i=0;e=a[i];i++){o+=e.href+'\\n'};o"
      end tell
      if albums is not missing value and albums is not "" then
          repeat with p in paragraphs 1 thru -2 of albums
              do shell script "open -jgagoogle\\ chrome " & quoted form of p
              delay 1
          end repeat
          repeat while loading of tabs of window 1 contains true
              delay 1
          end repeat
              tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
                  repeat while loading is true
                      delay 1
                  end repeat
                  set src to execute javascript "document.body.innerHTML"
                  if src contains "no photos in this album" then exit repeat
                  if src contains "you may not have permission to view this page" then return -- your account got restricted for a week by Facebook
                  set prev to 0
                  repeat
                      set y to execute javascript "document.querySelector('.fbTimelineStarGridSeparator').scrollIntoView();window.scrollY"
                      delay 1
                      if y is prev then exit repeat
                      set prev to y
                  end repeat
                  set out to execute javascript "o='';a=document.querySelectorAll('.tagWrapper i');for(i=0;e=a[i];i++)o+=e.getAttribute('style').replace(/.*?\\(/,'').replace(/\\).*/,'')+'\\n';o"
                  if out is not "" then
                      do shell script "printf %s " & quoted form of out & "|sed s/^/" & user & "\\ />>/tmp/albums"
                  end if
              end tell
          end if
        end tell
end repeat
```

I use a script like the one below to make a list of larger versions of images, which are up to 960 by 960 pixels large, so that they are not always the full size versions.

```
paragraphs of (do shell script "cat /tmp/ids_of_images")
repeat with photoid in result
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        close windows
        repeat until exists window 1
            do shell script "open -gagoogle\\ chrome https://www.facebook.com/" & photoid
            delay 5
        end repeat
        repeat while loading of tabs of window 1 contains true
            delay 1
        end repeat
        tell active tab of window 1
            set src to execute javascript "document.querySelector('.spotlight').src"
            if src is not missing value then
                do shell script "echo '" & src & "'>>/tmp/bigger"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Some photos are often not shown on the page for all photos but are shown when albums are browsed individually.

`https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<user id>&sk=photos_albums` is redirected to the page for the albums of a user, `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<user id>&sk=photos_all` is redirected to the page for all photos posted by a user, and `https://www.facebook.com/<fbid of image or user>` is redirected to the page for an image or a user.

After I have loaded more than about a thousand or a few thousand pages, my account sometimes gets restricted for a week so that I cannot view the profiles of users who are not my friends.

The number in the second underscore-delimited field in the filename of an image is the ID of the image, or for example `10102454385528521` in `12208495_10102454385528521_4749095086285673716_n.jpg`.

The user ID is the last number in an album identifier that starts with `a.` and the first number in an album identifier that starts with `fb.`.

`https://www.facebook.com/photo/download/?fbid=<fbid of photo>` used to be redirected to the full size version of an image, but that stopped working earlier this year.

`https://graph.facebook.com/<user id>/picture?width=9999` is redirected to the full size profile picture of a user, which still works even though the Graph API is no longer available.